# How to compute an exponent in matlab without getting inf even with vpa or sym?

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical

i have this exp function in matlab

```
a1=(exp(-beta0*abs(z-zaks)));
b1=(ohmi*exp(-2*beta0*H)*exp(-beta0*(z+zaks)))
c1=(ohmu*exp(beta0*(z+zaks)))
f1=(ohmu*ohmi*exp(-2*beta0*H)*exp(beta0*abs(z-zaks)))
g1=2*beta0*(1-(ohmu*ohmi*exp(-2*beta0*H)))
h1=(a1+b1+exp(c1)+f1)
j1=exp(h1)
gpm=j1/g1
```

with

```
beta0=1.411608078945960e+20 + 8.949434210398852e-26i
betai=[1.411608078945960e+20 + 8.949434210398852e-26i 1.411608078945960e+20 +   1.398349095374821e-26i 1.411608078945960e+20 + 1.398349095374821e-27i 1.411608078945960e+20 + 1.398349095374821e-26i]

ohmi=[9.803212783111246e-92 + 2.674639380309578e-46i 2.428723887707741e-93 + 4.457732300515962e-47i -2.428723887707741e-93 - 4.457732300515962e-47i;1.411608078945960e+20 + 1.398349095374821e-26i]

ohmu=1.004853842833425e-91 + 3.169942969255795e-46i
z=zaks=4950
H=5000
```

and it return to be inf
even if i had using vpa or sym in it
what should go wrong with this?

Comment: Can you add a bit of informations about how you'll be using the result of this operation afterwards in your code?

Comment: if this way could be work, i just have to divide it with something in +e032 order sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also depends on whether you used `vpa` correctly:

```
>> vpa(1e400)

ans =

Inf

>> vpa('1e400')

ans =

1.0e400
```

So you always have to prevent matlab from evaluating something large/small before using `vpa`. Now, this doesn't solve your problem, since

```
>> vpa(exp(1.3975e+024 +8.8599e-022*i))

ans =

Inf + Inf*i

>> vpa('exp(1.3975e+024 +8.8599e-022*i)')

ans =

Inf + Inf*i

>> exp(vpa('1.3975e+024 +8.8599e-022*i'))

ans =

RD_INF + RD_INF*i
```

so regardless of the approach you use, you will get infinity for all intents and purposes.

---

Why is that, you might ask? Consider that

```
exp(710)

ans =

   Inf
```

Now, your number is roughly equal to

```
exp(1397500000000000000000000)
```

or

```
10^606926538459794441764864
```

or

```
1e606926538459794441764864
```

Of course I ignored a teeny-tiny imaginary part, but that doesn't change much. You do realise that ***it's a very big number***, right?

So, as [@BillBokeey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342937/how-to-compute-an-exponent-in-matlab-without-getting-inf-even-with-vpa-or-sym#comment54481887_33342937) has already commented: what do you plan to do with this number? Your best options are probably doing anything you want on paper first, and reach a result that can be handled by a computer.

Comment: my apologize for suddenly just post a line from my work, i was trying to implement a formula from a paper, and those formulas lead me into this problem, so i just curious why it happen, because on the paper its possible to do it right, and yes i think i should do it on the paper first rather than all of sudden jump onto matlab

but is there's any way that i could compute it Mr Andras?

Comment: @arielrahardi as you see, even your best chances (i.e. symbolic math toolbox) give inf, since your number is just so mind-bogglingly large. Looking at your updated question: are you sure those numbers are correct? You seem to have some physical motivation behind your work, but it's very rare to have quantities with such different magnitudes (1e24 and 1e-24) next to each other. Are you sure that both the formulae and the parameters are correct?

Comment: yes, i am very sure with it, because i have another work with those order of magnitudes. and i have found no problem. This time i just want to try this new formula, and it turned to be like this